# Is it possible to create a method with variable arguments in COM interface?

Tags: com

I want to add a variable argument function in a COM interface is possible. i.e. something like printf function in C. Does COM support this?

Comment: Not directly, however you can take an array of VARIANT. (Make it a  SAFEARRAY for automation compatibility)

Comment: See [MIDL `vararg` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367304.aspx). It's smoke and mirrors really, syntactical sugar for clients written in VB and similar. On implementation side, it ends up as a `SAFEARRAY` of `VARIANT`s, as @MattMcNabb suggests.